# Extracting points that belong to a certain area of a RasterLayer (raster)

Tags: r, r-raster

As per title.

I have a "classified" `RasterLayer` object which has (apart from `NA`s) two fixed values, `0` and `1`. It is a kind of logical image.

I also have a data frame of points with their coordinates, in form of a `SpatialPointsDataFrame`.

How can I extract points belonging to a certain area (`0` or `1`)? Been searching into `raster-package` help but I couldn't find a solution.

Comment: @Pascal that did it. Will gladly accept your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can use `extract` from the `raster` package:**

> "Extract values from a Raster* object at the locations of other
>   spatial data (that is, perform a spatial query). You can use
>   coordinates (points), lines, polygons or an Extent (rectangle) object.
>   You can also use cell numbers to extract values."

```
values <- extract(x="YourRasterLayer", y="YourSpatialPointsDataFrame")
```

For more information type:

```
?raster::extract
```

or visit this [page](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/raster/docs/extract).